# Displaying message shown in command prompt in list box

Tags: c#, vb.net, dos, message, command-prompt

Actually I want to display the messages shown in cmd prompt like, if i do:

**Ping google.com -t**

The following message will be displayed in the cmd prompt:

```
Reply from 74.125.235.17: bytes=32 time=133ms TTL=51
Reply from 74.125.235.17: bytes=32 time=130ms TTL=51
Reply from 74.125.235.17: bytes=32 time=130ms TTL=51
Reply from 74.125.235.17: bytes=32 time=130ms TTL=51

Ping statistics for 74.125.235.17:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 130ms, Maximum = 133ms, Average = 130ms
```

I want to display the exact information into the list box of my program instantly when it is displayed in the command prompt not after whole process is completed. How can i do so? Any help? I am using C#/vb.net .

As in the **ping google.com -t**, I want to display the each reply message instantly in the list box.

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to utilize [async read on standardoutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx)... see also [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/FunWithProcesses.aspx)...

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/ReadProcessStdoutStderr.aspx?display=Mobile) you can find a solution for the described problem complete with source code... it even takes stderr into account...

Other interesting resources:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccf1tfx0.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo.aspx

Comment: This link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/ReadProcessStdoutStderr.aspx did the trick. Great, enjoy the bounty, Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Results As String

'The "Delegate" is used to correct the threading issue (Can't update control directly in VB.net 08/10), and invokes the needed text update.
Private Delegate Sub delUpdate()
Private Finished As New delUpdate(AddressOf UpdateText)

Private Sub UpdateText()
resultsTextBox.Text = Results
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim CMDThread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf CMDAutomate)
CMDThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub CMDAutomate()

Dim myprocess As New Process
Dim StartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

'Starts the CMD Prompt
StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True

'Required to redirect
StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False

'Disables the creation of a CMD Prompt outside application.
StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True


myprocess.StartInfo = StartInfo
myprocess.Start()
Dim SR As System.IO.StreamReader = myprocess.StandardOutput
Dim SW As System.IO.StreamWriter = myprocess.StandardInput

'Runs the command you entered...
SW.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)

'Exits CMD Prompt 
SW.WriteLine("exit")

'Displayes the results...
Results = SR.ReadToEnd
SW.Close()
SR.Close()

'Invokes Finished delegate, which updates textbox with the results text
Invoke(Finished)
End Sub
```

Comment: Mention that you need a tex box named resultsTextBox and a button named Button1

Comment: it's the output, there are some additional lines, you can remove them http://i.stack.imgur.com/RByCO.png

Comment: Your above code work but it shows the result in the list box after all the work is finished. But I want to display the message instantly i.e. in the case of ping google.com -t; I want to display each reply message instantly in the list box.

Comment: hm, maybe you have to deal with SR.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution for you.

- Redirect output to C:\ping.txt

  "Ping google.com -t > C:\ping.txt"
- Read ping.txt every x second(s)

  File.ReadAllText("C:\ping.txt")
- Update ListBox in an UI safe thread refer to

  [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)